# Getting this error in “bash:metagoofil: command not found” in Kali Linux

Tags: linux, kali-linux

I am new to using Kali Linux, however when reading other tutorials it seems Metagoofil should have already been installed when installing Kali itself.

I am trying to use the `metagoofil` command but the error I am getting is:

```
bash:metagoofil: command not found
```

When I type command:

```
locate metagoofil
```

All results are in the `/usr/share/icons` directory. There are no files related to Metagoofil in the `/usr/bin` folder, similarly there is no independent folder `metagoofil`.

Can any one help with this?

Comment: Did you install it first? Try `apt-get install metagoofil` first then retry.

Comment: Thank you that worked! I was unaware that, that was the method of installing tools on Kali

Comment: apt-get install metagoofil didn't work on a stock install of Kali 2.0: E: Unable to locate package metagoofil (after apt-get update/upgrade)

Answer (score 0):

`apt-get install metagoofil` didn't find the package on my Kali 2.0 - though I've noticed that several common tools are not found using this method, I think there is an issue with my sources.list file.

Anyway - I got the tool by going to `edge-security.com` and downloading the .tar.gz file, and just extracting it. When doing so, however, there appeared to be a dependency problem and so I had to download the 'Blackhat' version (also on the site) which worked no problem.

I'm struggling to actually get any results with it, mind, but it works.  Apologies if my language isn't quite right - I'm new to Kali / Linux also.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your `sources.list` file at `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

Then do an `apt-get update`.

This should work.